# How does Elasticsearch query by text so fast?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been learning about Elasticsearch for some time now.

I want to see if the following statement es correct:

Elasticsearch manages such high speeds because you can split data that is in the same index between several nodes that will take a GET query and run it at the same time.

Meaning if I have three pieces of data in the "book" index

```
{"name": "Pinocchio"}
{"name": "Frozen"}
{"name": "Diary of A Wimpy Kid"}
```

And I decide to give the cluster three nodes, each node will hold one of the three books and therefore speed up my get request 3x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's much more to it, but that's pretty much what happens behind the scene.

Provided your index has three primary shards and each shard lands on a different node and contains one of the documents in your question, when you execute a query on your index, the query gets broadcast to each of the shards of your index and [is executed on each node in parallel](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_query_phase.html) to search the documents on that node.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to make this clear!

Comment: @Val is querying all the shards(of an index) in parallel a good design vs finding the shard holding the required data using consistent hashing & then querying the same shard?

Comment: @wayne it depends on your use case. Feel free to create a new question explaining what you're after and we can research what's best for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned the one of the advantages of Elasticsearch as it distributes data (Shards and Replica) on multiple server and query will be executed parallel. it is useful for High Availibility as well.

Another reason is due to how elasticsearch internally store data. It use Lucene which stored data in inverted Index.

You can check below link for more explanation:

[Why Elasticsearch is fatser comapre to raw SQL command](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/66q413/why_is_elastic_search_faster_at_querying_compared/)

[How Elasticsearch Search So Fast?](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-elasticsearch-search-so-fast-248630b70ba4)

[How is Elasticsearch so fast?](https://tekclansolutions.com/2020/03/31/how-is-elasticsearch-so-fast/)

Comment: Thank you as well @Sagar\ Patel for taking the time to answer and make it clear. Wish I could accept more than one answer :(

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why elastic search is faster is because of the presence of Inverted Index!.